# Importing external libraries/Packages from an ImageJ/Fiji script

Tags: jython, imagej, java

I am writing an imageJ/Fiji plugin in Jython using the Fiji script editor. I need to import external numerical libraries such as ParallelColt to help me handle multidimensional matrices.

I began with ParallelColt by placing its jar file in the java folder inside Fiji:
"Fiji.app/java/macosx-java3d/Home/lib/ext” 
Then I tried importing it by writing: 
"import ParallelColt” or more specifically "from ParallelColt import jplasma"
And I get an error of module not found.

I tried placing the jar inside the Fiji plugins folder instead but with
still no success. I also tried by using the folder with all the java classes
of ParallelColt instead of the jar file and I still was not able to import
the classes from my script.

The question perhaps that I am simply asking is how to import java libraries from a Jython script. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

## 1. Dependencies

In order to depend on a complex third party software project with multiple JAR files, you need to make sure you have placed *all* the dependencies of the project (i.e., all the JAR files it needs) into `ImageJ.app/jars`.

One way to do it is to [find the dependencies on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) and then use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle to download them.

In your case, you can do this with Maven by crafting the following `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>dummy</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.parallelcolt</groupId>
      <artifactId>parallelcolt</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.mikera</groupId>
      <artifactId>vectorz</artifactId>
      <version>0.34.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then executing:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This will result in the following files in the `target/dependencies` folder:

```
  29087 AMDJ-1.0.1.jar
   8687 BTFJ-1.0.1.jar
  19900 COLAMDJ-1.0.1.jar
  55638 JKLU-1.0.0.jar
1194003 arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar
  31162 core-lapack-0.1.jar
 212836 csparsej-1.1.1.jar
  88639 edn-java-0.4.4.jar
  91793 jplasma-1.2.0.jar
 762778 jtransforms-2.4.0.jar
 237344 junit-4.8.2.jar
   8693 mathz-0.3.0.jar
 131210 netlib-java-0.9.3.jar
  66134 optimization-1.0.jar
4111744 parallelcolt-0.10.1.jar
  14028 randomz-0.3.0.jar
 593015 vectorz-0.34.0.jar
```

Move these into your `ImageJ.app/jars` folder, and you should be good to go—though beware of multiple versions of the same library, since ImageJ cannot handle that right now.

## 2. Class references

The line `from ParallelColt import jplasma` is not valid. That is, there is no `ParallelColt.jplasma` Java class or package. You can verify this yourself from the command line:

```bash
$ find-class() { for f in *.jar; do result=$(jar tf "$f" | grep -l "$@"); if [ "$result" != "" ]; then echo $f; fi; done; }
$ cd ImageJ.app/jars
$ find-class jplasma
```

Two JAR files have classes containing that string:

```
core-lapack-0.1.jar
jplasma-1.2.0.jar
```

And taking a look inside of them quickly reveals that the package names do not start with `ParallelColt`:

```
$ jar tf jplasma-1.2.0.jar | grep jplasma
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/benchmark/
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/test/
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/example/
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/benchmark/DgelsBenchmark.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/benchmark/DposvBenchmark.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/benchmark/DgesvBenchmark.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/Barrier.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/test/DposvTest.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/test/DgelsTest.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/test/DgesvTest.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/Dgels.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/Dgeqrf.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/Dglobal$Dplasma_cntrl.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/Dplasma.class
...
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/Dglobal$Dplasma_aux.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/tdouble/Pdormqr.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/example/DposvExample.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/example/DgesvExample.class
edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/example/DgelsExample.class
```

Rather, if you would like to use, e.g., `edu.emory.mathcs.jplasma.tdouble.Dplasma`, you need to import it as:

```python
from edu.emory.mathcs.jplasma.tdouble import Dplasma
```

Here is a port of [DgelsExample.java](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/jplasma/code/trunk/src/edu/emory/mathcs/jplasma/example/DgelsExample.java) from the [JPlasma](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jplasma) distribution which works in the ImageJ Script Editor:

```python
from edu.emory.mathcs.jplasma.tdouble import Dplasma
from java.lang import Math
import jarray

M = 15;
N = 10;
NRHS = 5;

A = jarray.zeros(M * N, 'd')
B = jarray.zeros(M * NRHS, 'd')

# Initialize A
for i in range(0, M):
    for j in range(0, N):
        A[M * j + i] = 0.5 - Math.random()

# Initialize B
for i in range(0, M):
    for j in range(0, NRHS):
        B[M * j + i] = Math.random()

# Plasma Initialize
Dplasma.plasma_Init(M, N, NRHS)

# Allocate T
T = Dplasma.plasma_Allocate_T(M, N)

# Solve the problem
INFO = Dplasma.plasma_DGELS(Dplasma.PlasmaNoTrans, M, N, NRHS, A, 0, M, T, 0, B, 0, M)

# Plasma Finalize
Dplasma.plasma_Finalize()

if INFO < 0:
    print("-- Error in DgelsExample example !")
else:
    print("-- Run successfull !")
```

See the [Jython Scripting](http://wiki.imagej.net/Jython_Scripting) page of the ImageJ Wiki for further information on writing Jython scripts.

One final parting comment: the ImageJ Script Editor was really designed as a tool to develop single-class scripts and plugins that rely on components already present in the installation. My suggestion for a project like this with many dependencies would be to instead code in Java using an IDE such as Eclipse, because such IDEs offer many more productivity enhancing features. You can use AST-based auto-complete to explore the API of the libraries you're using, and browse javadocs and sources easily without doing web searches.

Comment: Sorry, for replying a little late. I did see your message but I wanted to try all the stuff out before replying. I got the dependencies to work using Maven but I think I will take up your suggestion to do this project in an IDE (specifically Eclipse). I plan on using Jython using the PyDev plugin. I know you have already helped out enough, but I would like your advice on one more issue. Should I code purely in Java or should I stick with Jython. Are there some drawbacks or limitations to using Jython? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Jython's two-edged sword is that it's a dynamically typed language, which means you have flexibility, but don't benefit from the nice code completion features of Eclipse. I am guessing PyDev mitigates that somewhat, but it will not be as powerful in that way as developing in Java would be. Some benefits of Jython over Java are also [outlined on the Jython website](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/whatis.html). In particular, many claim Jython is faster for prototyping. Personally though I usually code in Java in Eclipse with the [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) plugin.